Is it possible to vectorize a loop of if-else statement in Python?
I am wondering the possibility of turning a for loop with several if-else statements into vectorize version in Python. Suppose I have several numpy arrays a,b,c,d , where a,b,c,d have the same length. I need to write the following for loop to calculate the value of c and 'd'
    for i in range(2, len(a)):
        if (
            a[i - 2] < b[i - 2]
            and a[i - 1] > b[i - 1]
            and c[i - 1] == 0
        ):
            d[i] = -1
            c[i] = c[i - 1] - 1
        elif (
            a[i - 2] > b[i - 2]
            and a[i - 1] < b[i - 1]
            and c[i - 1] == 0
        ):
            d[i] = 1
            c[i] = c[i - 1] + 1
        else: 
            d[i] = 0  
            c[i] = c[i - 1]

The catch is that the size of arrays is 10^5 and I have to execute this for-loop for 10^3' times, the time complexity is O(10^8)` which is very slow  and computational heavy to use for loop with if-else statement. I am wondering is there a vectorized or faster way to do these operation in Python?
I have ask ChatGPT for helps, it suggests that turning the if , elif conditions to
condition1 = (
    (a[:-2] < b[:-2]) &
    (a[1:-1] > b[1:-1]) &
    (d 1:-1] == 0)
)

condition2 = (
    (a[:-2] > b[:-2]) &
    (a[1:-1] < b[1:-1]) &
    (d 1:-1] == 0)
)

, respectively. Then, it uses np.where to execute the conditions
c[2:] = np.where(condition1, -1,0)
d[2:] = np.where(condition1, d[1:-1] - 1, d[1:-1])

c[2:] = np.where(condition2, 1, 0)
d[2:] = np.where(condition2, d1:-1] + 1, d[1:-1])

however, these results are not correct comparing the for-loop result. Beside, I don't know where is the condition for else statement.

'vectorization' in numpy means using compiled methods to do the iterations.  Your task is inherently sequential, one value of c depends on the previous.  Except for a few cases like cumsum that's hard to do with a finite set of precompiled building blocks.

You can stop your loop once one of the first branches is reached, because from then on c[i-1] will never be zero again -- afterwards just fill the rest of c with the previous c value. Also c[i] = c[i - 1] - 1 is just c[i] = -1 if c[i-1] needs to be zero. (Maybe you oversimplified your actual code for this question, though)

To speed-up the processing I suggest to try numba:
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit
def compute_numba(a, b, c, d):
    for i in range(2, len(a)):
        if a[i - 2] < b[i - 2] and a[i - 1] > b[i - 1] and c[i - 1] == 0:
            d[i] = -1
            c[i] = c[i - 1] - 1
        elif a[i - 2] > b[i - 2] and a[i - 1] < b[i - 1] and c[i - 1] == 0:
            d[i] = 1
            c[i] = c[i - 1] + 1
        else:
            d[i] = 0
            c[i] = c[i - 1]


np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)
b = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)
c = np.zeros(10)
d = np.zeros(10)

compute_numba(a, b, c, d)
print(c)
print(d)


Benchmark:
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import njit


def compute_normal(a, b, c, d):
    for i in range(2, len(a)):
        if a[i - 2] < b[i - 2] and a[i - 1] > b[i - 1] and c[i - 1] == 0:
            d[i] = -1
            c[i] = c[i - 1] - 1
        elif a[i - 2] > b[i - 2] and a[i - 1] < b[i - 1] and c[i - 1] == 0:
            d[i] = 1
            c[i] = c[i - 1] + 1
        else:
            d[i] = 0
            c[i] = c[i - 1]


compute_numba = njit(compute_normal)

np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)
b = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)
c = np.zeros(10)
d = np.zeros(10)

# this also compiles the function
compute_numba(a, b, c, d)


def setup_arrays(N=10**5):
    a = np.random.randint(1, 100, N)
    b = np.random.randint(1, 100, N)
    c = np.zeros(N)
    d = np.zeros(N)
    return a, b, c, d


t_numba = timeit(
    "compute_numba(a, b, c, d)",
    setup="a, b, c, d = setup_arrays()",
    number=10**3,
    globals=globals(),
)

t_normal = timeit(
    "compute_normal(a, b, c, d)",
    setup="a, b, c, d = setup_arrays()",
    number=10**3,
    globals=globals(),
)

print(f"{t_normal=}")
print(f"{t_numba=}")

Prints on my computer AMD 5700x:
t_normal=58.72821913100779
t_numba=0.5004643630236387

So quite a nice speed-up.

Numba automatically performs a wraparound check if indices could be negative, by only looking at the indices. If you just look at them a wraparound case could happen, but practically this is obviously not the case. By changing the indices to positive inlucding a modifiaction of the loop bounds, the function could be another 40% faster.

Firstly of all, you (or chatgpt) mixed c and d (the original code tests a,b and c, to decide to affect -1,0,1 to d. The attempted answer tests a,b,d to decide to affect -1,0,1 to c)
Secondly, your chatgpt answer doesnot chain correctly the if/then/else to create a if cond1 thenCase1 else (if cond2 thenCase2 elseCase3).
But that you can do it yourself if you understand what np.where does (np.where(arrayOfBoolConds, thenArray, elseArray)).
For example
d[2:] = np.where(condition1, -1, np.where(condition2, 1, 0))

And thirdly, your problem is not directly vectorizable. At least not if you consider it generally speaking (maybe, while thinking harder on the specific of your probem, we may turn it into a combination of vectorized and cumulative functions). And ChatGPT failed to see that.
You cannot do c[2:] = vectorizedFunctionOf(c[1:-1]) and expect it to iterate correctly. Anyway, "vectorize" and "iterate" are two contradictory words. Vectorization is the fact to process simulateneously cases (the word is used with numpy to say that, from the point of view of python, it is done in one numpy's call, even if inside that call, an iteration may occur. But strictly speaking, vectorization is what happened inside Cray's supercomputers, or intel MMX and the next instructions — and then, of course, new vectorized processors: several identical instructions are executed at the same time on different data)
That being said, there are some functions, like cumsum or cumprod that are being called "vectorized" in numpy's world, while doing some iterative process (but again, in a single numpy's call). Maybe they could help.
If c wasn't also part of the condition, I would have suggested that c[2:] is c[1]+d[2:].cumsum(). But you need a fully computed c to execute the np.where, and you need those np.where to compute c. So, not vectorizable, unless you manage to write the algorithm differently.
Generally speaking (outside some specific cases that can be done with some ingenious combinations of cumsum), you can't vectorized iterative process.
